# Bad request when trying to upload report unit in JasperServer

Tags: java, api, rest, jasperserver, bad-request

I'm facing a bad request when trying to upload a report unit using   `/jrs-rest-java-client`.

I have been looking for the solution in the JasperServer community, but I couldn't find an answer.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.exceptions.BadRequestException: Bad Request
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.exceptions.handling.DefaultErrorHandler.handleStatusCodeError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:111)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.exceptions.handling.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:68)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.JerseyRequest.executeRequest(JerseyRequest.java:189)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.core.JerseyRequest.post(JerseyRequest.java:140)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.apiadapters.resources.SingleResourceAdapter.uploadMultipartResource(SingleResourceAdapter.java:204)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.apiadapters.resources.support.processor.CommonOperationProcessorImpl.create(CommonOperationProcessorImpl.java:46)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.apiadapters.resources.support.decorator.ReportUnitResourceOperationProcessorDecorator.createInFolder(ReportUnitResourceOperationProcessorDecorator.java:46)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.jaxrs.client.TestJasperDeploy.uploadingReportunit(TestJasperDeploy.java:170)
```

My code to initialize JasperServer is

```
          Properties props = new Properties() {  
             setProperty("url", "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/");
             setProperty("contentMimeType", "JSON");
             setProperty("acceptMimeType", "JSON");
             setProperty("connectionTimeout", "");
             setProperty("readTimeout", "");
             setProperty("authenticationType", "SPRING");
             setProperty("restrictedHttpMethods", "false");
             setProperty("logHttpEntity", "true");
             setProperty("logHttp", "true");
             setProperty("handleErrors", "true");   
         }  
     };

     RestClientConfiguration configuration = RestClientConfiguration.loadConfiguration(props);
     client = new JasperserverRestClient(configuration);  
     session = client.authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin");
```

And my code to upload the report unit is:

```
//this report has no subreports
// and requires a datasource not included in this example
ClientReferenceableFile jrxml = new ClientReferenceableFile() {
     @ Override
    public String getUri() {
        //my local  jrxm report
        String fileString1 = "C:/reports/documentos/subreports/SR_D_01_nome_funcionario.jrxml";
        return fileString1;
    }
};

ClientReportUnit repunit = new ClientReportUnit();
repunit.setJrxml(jrxml);

//this is the report location on the server
repunit.setUri("/reports/documentos/subreports");
repunit.setLabel("label report unit");
repunit.setDescription("descricao report");
ClientFile clifile = new ClientFile();
clifile.setType(ClientFile.FileType.jrxml);
clifile.setUri("/reports/documentos/subreports");
ReportUnitResourceBuilder repUnut = session.resourcesService().resource(repunit).withJrxml(repunit.getUri(), clifile);
repUnut.createInFolder("/reports");
```

Comment: In your upload code, which line is line 170? The last line?

Comment: Line 170 calls the second part of the code: the error is in the last line:
    repUnut.createInFolder("/reports");

Comment: Please edit your answer and add these details: what resources your reportUnit needs to use and where they are located(already on server or to be uploaded) and if the report uses any subreports

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the API properly in this case. This is what you should have:

```
ClientReportUnit reportUnit = new ClientReportUnit();
reportUnit.setLabel("label report unit");
reportUnit.setDescription("descricao report");

ClientFile clientFile = new ClientFile();
clientFile.setType(ClientFile.FileType.jrxml);
clientFile.setLabel("Main Report");

FileInputStream fis;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/report_template.jrxml");

    ReportUnitResourceBuilder reportUnitResourceBuilder = session.resourcesService().resource(reportUnit).withJrxml(fis, clientFile);
    reportUnitResourceBuilder.createInFolder("/reports/documentos/subreports");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // do something with the error
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code solved our problem. It is now deploying the file as a report but the input controls are not uploaded (when i execute the report ir returns an error message "Empty report"). Is it possible to set the controls in the client report unit? And how? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is what we are trying to do:

ClientInputControl cli1 =  new ClientInputControl();
  cli1.setUri("/datatypes/ANO");
  cli1.setLabel("ANO");
  
    List<ClientReferenceableInputControl> inputControls=new ArrayList<ClientReferenceableInputControl>();
    inputControls.add(cli1);
    reportUnit.setInputControls(inputControls);